# What is wrong with this OpenCv code?

Tags: opencv

I am trying frame difference in this opencv code (C API).
   It gives me an error:

```
Assertion failed (src1.size() == dst.size() && src1.type() == dst. type()) in unknown function, file ........\ocv\opencv\src\cxcore\cxarithm.cpp , line 1563.
```

The code is as follow. (When I try to run a video file, this program seems to run without any error, but when I am trying to capture from laptop camera, it gives this error. How do I fix this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
int key=0;

//CvCapture *capture=cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
CvCapture *capture=cvCaptureFromAVI("cmake.avi");
IplImage *frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
IplImage *currframe=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
IplImage *dstframe=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
 int fps = ( int )cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS );
cvNamedWindow("output",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

while(key!='x'){
            currframe=cvCloneImage(frame);
    frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);

    //cvCopy(frame,currframe,0);
    frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);

    cvSub(frame,currframe,dstframe);
    if(key==27) break;
    cvShowImage("output",dstframe);
    key = cvWaitKey( 1000 / fps );

}

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
cvDestroyWindow("output");

 return 0;
  }
```

Comment: please try *not* to use the deprecated c-api. it's only around for maintenance reasons, you should not write any new code with it.

Comment: Yes I have been made aware of that recently. I will be shifting to the c++ API, but for now I would appreciate if someone can point out the reason for the error in this code.

Comment: Duly noted and corrected. Now, what is causing the above error?

Comment: start checking if the capture opened, an image was read, the footwork ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that you are trying to do an operation that needs images of the same size and type.  If you run your code in a debugger you can see which line this occurs on.

It is probably one of the destination images you are creating. A t least in the C++ api it is best not to create destination images but just declare them and let the function allocate what it needs